# Require gold standard data for face recognition

Tags: correlation

One of the demerits for my research is have not compared with gold standard data, can someone help me how to compare my data with available gold standard data for face recognition.
Would like to know what is gold standard data and is there any data available for face recognition.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you tell us some more about your data and the sorts of comparisons you'd like to make? The more information you provide, the better advice we'll be able to give!

Comment: In addition, be aware that asking for datasets (if that is what you are doing) is off-topic for CV (see our [help center](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that what you are asking is clarification as to what the term "gold standard" means and how it applies to prediction. I assume this is not about how you might go about obtaining such data or predictive model output from your specific context.

We can assume there are two basic types of prediction: prediction of continuous measures (such as the log of the amount of rainfall on a given day) or prediction of binary measures (such as presence or absence of a particular antibody for a disease). Validating these models in isolation is well documented with split-sample validation, performance measures (RMSE, AUC, etc.), and a host of tools.

These tools *do not* provide a way to compare the incremental performance index of two competing models. It's rarely the case that prediction models exist within a vacuum with which there are no other predictive models to compare the performance of a novel model. When researchers come together and offer up many models, the test of time and outsider perspective will allow (usually) one model to surface as being of the best predictive accuracy (provided that it's cheap and easy enough to use for its intended application). This usually qualifies a model to be called the "gold standard". Knowing how a new model compares to the gold standard is part of the process of proposing it as a useful alternative for some (or all) applications.

Comparing models to a gold standard may involve: calculating RMSE differences for continuous outcomes (Brier score for binary outcomes), calculating c-statistics and 95% confidence intervals for binary outcomes, constructing calibration plots, and/or calculating risk stratification tables (for nested models).

What the reviewer is probably asking you to do is access the literature and find an instance of someone else who has done what you are doing and to show that you can do them one better.

Comment: Thanks AdamO, The answer is very clear and exactly what am looking for. Thank you

Comment: @M.George Welcome to the site. If you found an answer to be correct, mark it as such using the check mark by the upvote arrow. You needn't upvote a question you mark as correct, since upvotes are for "good" answers (sometimes a bit tangential) and checks are for "correct" answers (which can be good or not good). This is a service to others who may have the same question in the future and use search before asking it.